# how to get table from database using php when 2 input values given?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

```
<form action="applications.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
Value1: <input type="text" name="value"><br>
Value2: <input type="text" name="value1"><br>
<input type="submit"         onmouseover="this.style.cursor=\'pointer\';"OnMouseOut="this.style.cursor=\'default\';">
 </form>

<?php
if (isset($_GET['value=20'&&'value1=40']))
{
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$hostname = 'localhost';
$dataname = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die("Connection failed: ");
$selected = mysql_select_db('testdb',$dataname) or die("Could not select table1");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table1`");
$last = '';
echo "<table>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
    </tr>";
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 echo"<tr>
         <td>".$row['0']."</th>
         <td>".$row['1']."</td>
    </tr>"; 
    }
mysql_close($dataname);
}
?>
```

For eg if i have entered value1=20 and value2=40 then i have to get the "table1' as result. Can anyone help me to correct this code or tell me the anyother way to do this.

Comment: What is the login on this?

Comment: you want table name as a result?

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: you want data according to values entered from the table?

Comment: I want the whole table (n*n) as result when the input is given as value1=20 and value2=40.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guard against the values is wrong...
if (isset($_GET['value=20'&&'value1=40']))

should be

if ((isset($_GET['value']) && ($_GET['value'] == '20') &&
(isset($_GET['value2']) && ($_GET['value2'] == '40'))

Comment: Its not displaying table on the Html page on clicking submit..Can you please help me.. Am new to PHP.. Let me know if you want additional details on this code

Comment: Thank you LuckyBurger :) It worked :)